# How to pass a state value from one component to another component at the same level

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a bit confused as I need to pass a value within one component to another component at the same level.

My App.js has the following components:

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <nav className={classes.drawer}>
        </nav>
        <div className={classes.app}>
          <Header onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} jobAddress={jobAddress} />
          <Content />  
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

Based on a `jobAddress` value (123 Main Street) provided by the user within the `<Content />` component, how can I feed this `jobAddress` value back up into the `<Header />` component as a prop/state value as I want to make sure that whenever the value is altered within `<Content />`, it is also reflected within `<Header />`

I have not provided any code as I basically am not sure how to approach this. I have read up on React Context API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have state in your `App.js` component. Such as

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

...

const [jobAddress, setJobAddress] = useState('123 Main Street')

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <nav className={classes.drawer}>
        </nav>
        <div className={classes.app}>
          <Header onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} jobAddress={jobAddress} />
          <Content setJobAddress={setJobAddress} />  
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

Then in your `Content` Component, you just call `setJobAddress` with the new address you want, like `setJobAddress('123 Xyz St');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do you receive or set the `jobAddress`, if it is fetched from the server-side, then you should do the fetching in the parent. If it is a state, you should manage the state outside.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [jobAddress, setJobAddress] = useState("");
  // some code omitted

  const handleJobAddressChange = jobAddress => setJobAddress(jobAddress);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <nav className={classes.drawer}>
        </nav>
        <div className={classes.app}>
          <Header
            onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
            jobAddress={jobAddress}
          />
          <Content
            onJobAddressChange={handleJobAddressChange}
            jobAddress={jobAddress}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

In `<Content/>`, get the `jobAddress` and the `onJobAddressChange` from the `props` instead of defining them in `<Content/>`.